# Error marshalling old xsd file with jaxb2-maven-plugin 3.1.0

Tags: java, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I have an xsd file which I use to generate DTO files with `jaxb2-maven-plugin` `2.5.0` under `Java 8`.

Now I migrated to `jaxb2-maven-plugin` `3.1.0` (forced by previous migration to `Java 11`) and I'm getting this error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: not an external binding file. The root element must be {https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb}bindings but it is {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}schema
```

The xsd file starts like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="https://www.xxxxx.es/xxxxx/ApiEstandar"
    targetNamespace="https://www.xxxxx.es/xxxxx/ApiEstandar"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    
    <xs:complexType name="GenericRequest"/>
    
    <xs:complexType name="GenericResponse">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="codigoRespuesta" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="descripcionRespuesta" type="xs:string" />
```

If I change (like it seems to ask the previous error message) the `xmlns:xs` value to:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb"
```

Then Eclipse complains about `"xs:string"` name not being resolved.

I'm not sure about how to configure correctly the xsd file.

EDIT:
Answering to Laurent Schoelens I'm not using binding files and the plugin configuration in pom.xml is this one:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>xjc</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <locale>en</locale>
                <packageName>com.xxxxx.services.xxxxxservice.soap.services.model</packageName>
                <sources>
                    <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd/APIEstandar_v1.0.xsd</source>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Do you use binding files ? Could you share the plugin actual configuration ? Also, do you plan to move to jakarta-based dependency ? Thanks for your answers

Comment: @LaurentSchoelens Added requested info in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Many thanks for the quick answer. Could you please also tell me if you plan to move to jakarta-based dependency (JAXB3 or JAXB4) ? Or do you want to stick with JAXB 2.3 ?

Comment: @LaurentSchoelens I could move to another plugin if needed.

Comment: Yes but you didn't answer my question : do you plan moving to JAXB 3/4 or do you want to stick to JAXB 2 ? What is the jaxb dependencies you include in your application ?

Answer (score 1):

Starting from v3, the maven-plugin `org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin` targets `JAXB3`, which is `jakarta`-based.

If you need JDK11 support and v2.x of the `jaxb2-maven-plugin` doesn't bring support of JDK11 : you can check at [`org.jvnet.jaxb:jaxb-maven-plugin:2.0.9`](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/tree/jaxb-tools-2.x) plugin which is quite similar to Codehaus plugin and supports JDK11, JDK17 and even JDK21.